# How to prove that $x+y \ge 2$ for $xy = 1$ and both positive?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

For every $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $x,y>0$ and that satisfy the condition xy=1, the following will hold:

$$x+y\ge 2$$

Steps I took and my thoughts on this:

$$xy=1\Rightarrow \frac { xy }{ x } =\frac { 1 }{ x } \Rightarrow y=\frac { 1 }{ x } \quad and\quad xy=1\Rightarrow \frac { xy }{ y } =\frac { 1 }{ y } \Rightarrow x=\frac { 1 }{ y } $$

$$x\cdot \frac { 1 }{ x } =1\quad and\quad y\cdot \frac { 1 }{ y } =1$$

$$x+\frac { 1 }{ x } \ge 2\quad and\quad \frac { 1 }{ y } +y\ge 2$$

$$x(x+\frac { 1 }{ x } )\ge (2)x\quad and\quad y(\frac { 1 }{ y } +y)\ge (2)y$$

$$x^{ 2 }+1\ge 2x\quad and\quad y^2+1\ge 2y$$

$$x^{ 2 }-2x+1\ge 0\quad and\quad y^{ 2 }-2y+1\ge 0$$

$$(x-1)^{ 2 }\ge 0\quad and\quad (y-1)^{ 2 }\ge 0$$

$$x\in\mathbb{R} \quad and \quad y\in\mathbb{R} $$

I'm not sure where I am going wrong, but I don't know how to organize my thoughts about this in order to prove it with a formal mathematical proof. I'd like to be guided in the right direction. Hints are much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe what you want to do is the following :

Because $y=\frac 1x$, all we have to prove is that for $x\gt 0$,
$$x+\frac 1x\ge 2\tag1$$
For $x\gt 0$, this is equivalent to
$$(x-1)^2\ge 0,$$
which always holds. So, $(1)$ holds for $x\gt 0$.

Comment: So do I have to prove it for $y>0$ in the same manner and them I'm done?

Comment: @Cherry_Developer: No, you don't have to do that. Note that $x+y=x+\frac 1x$. So, my answer shows that $x+y\ge 2$ for $x\gt 0,y\gt 0$ such that $xy=1$.

Comment: That's all there is to this proof? Manipulate it to a form in which it demonstrates that it holds for $x>0$

Comment: @Cherry_Developer: Yes, that's all.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, $xy=1\implies \sqrt{xy}=1$ and so $x+y-2=(\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y})^2\ge0$.

Answer (score 1):

You actually have most of the pieces; you need to stop manipulating and think about putting them together.

If $xy=1$, then $y=\frac1x$, and

$$x+y=x+\frac1x=\frac{x^2+1}x\;.$$

Suppose that this is less than $2$; then since $x>0$, we can multiply by $x$ to find that $x^2+1<2x$, or $x^2-2x+1<0$. Now factor the lefthand side of that last inequality to get a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

$$
x+\dfrac{1}{x}=\dfrac{x^2+1}{x}=\dfrac{(x-1)^2+2x}{x}=\dfrac{(x-1)^2}{x}+2 
$$
so, for $x>0$:
$$
x+\dfrac{1}{x}-2>0
$$